# configuration.isOn.toggle() Not working in Custom Toggle in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have made a screen where I used a custom toggle. But when I am tapping on the toggle button, it's always printing "isOff" because the configuration.toggle value is not updating and is always set to false.

```
struct TestToggleView: View {
    @Binding private var isOn: Bool

     init(isOn: Binding<Bool>) {
         _isOn = isOn
     }

     public var body: some View {
         Toggle(isOn: $isOn, label: {
             Text("Hi)
         })
         .toggleStyle(ToggleStyle())
     }
}
```

```
private struct ButtonToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {


    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
                             configuration.label
                             Text("Yes")
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                          .onTapGesture {
                              configuration.isOn.toggle()
                              if configuration.isOn {
                                  print("isOn")
                              } else {
                                  print("isOff")
                          }
                          }
                          .onAppear {
                              print(configuration.isOn)
                   }
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Well, you should ***not*** name your custom ToggleStyle `ToggleStyle`.
2. To change the isOn value you have to go to the wrappedValue:
   `configuration.$isOn.wrappedValue.toggle()`

Here is a complete example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isOn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $isOn, label: {
            Text("Hi") })
            .toggleStyle(MyToggleStyle())
    }
}

struct MyToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            configuration.label
            Text(configuration.isOn ? "Yes" : "No")
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        
            .onTapGesture {
                configuration.$isOn.wrappedValue.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's still not working

Comment: I have updated the post.. The isOn variable that I am using is @Binding

Comment: You cannot declare a `private @Binding` - it should be a `@State`, or non-private Binding, so another view can pass a `@State` or `@ObservedObjec` var into it.

Comment: I did exactly what you mentioned, and removed private from binding but it's not working. Could you please try once with the binding and let me know if it works

Comment: it works with me. what / how do you pass the binding? Just add the code of the calling view.

Comment: I am simply taking the binding in init from the calling view. I have updated the question code for more detail.

Comment: I was sending .constant in the binding which was causing the issue. Thanks a lot for your help.